# Swapping dictionary keys and values works only on 3 key-value pair dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's a function that is supposed to swap dictionary keys and values. `{'a': 3}` is supposed to become `{3: 'a'}`.

```py
def change_keys_values(d):
    for key in d:
        value = d[key]
        del d[key]
        d[value] = key
     
    return d
```

I've realized that this function shouldn't work because I'm changing dictionary keys during iteration. This is the error I get: "dictionary keys changed during iteration". However, I don't get this error on a three key-value pair dictionary. So, while `{'a': 3, 't': 8, 'r': 2, 'z': 44, 'u': 1, 'b': 4}` results in the above mentioned error, `{'a': 3, 't': 8, 'r': 2}` gets solved without any issues. I'm using python 3. What is causing this?

Comment: WARNING: Don't modify a collection over which you are iterating.

Comment: I get that. But, why does this work on {'a': 3, 't': 8, 'r': 2} ?

Comment: It will work in random scenarios and not in others. What you need is consistent, predictable working behavior. See @Miind 's answer

Answer (score 2):

You must never modify a `dictionary` inside a `loop`. The reason is the way the dictionaries are often implemented.

**Hash Tables**

Basically, when you create a dictionary, each item is indexed using the hash value of the key.

**Dictionaries are implemented sparsely**

Another implementation detail involves the fact that dictionaries are implemented in a sparse manner. Namely, when you create a dictionary, there are empty places in memory (called buckets). When you add or remove elements from a dictionary, it may hit a threshold where the dictionary key hashes are re-evaluated and as a consequence, the indexes are changed.

Roughly speaking, these two points are the reason behind the problem you are observing.

**Moral Point:** Never modify a dictionary inside a loop of any kind.

Here's a simple code to do what you want:

```
def change_keys_values(d):
    new_dict = {value: key for key, value in d.items()}
    return new_dict
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify that the values are unique, after that, no problem :)
But be sure not to change a dictionary while parsing it. Otherwise, you could encounter an already changed index that get's interpreted twice or even more. I suggest making a new variable (a copy):

```
def invert(dict_: dict) -> dict:
    if list(set(dict_.values())) == list(dict_.values()):  # evaluates if "inverting key:value" is possible (if keys are unique)
        return {b: a for a, b in dict_.items()}
    else:
        raise ValueError("Dictionary values contain duplicates. Inversion not possible!")


print(invert({"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4}))  # works

print(invert({"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 3}))  # fails
```

Comment: This does not answer the question that is being asked. You are creating a new dictionary, while the question is obviously why the error arises in one case, and not in the other.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your issue, just iterate over copy, not the original `dict`:

```py
import copy

def change_keys_values(d):
    for key in copy.deepcopy(d):
        value = d[key]
        del d[key]
        d[value] = key

    return d
```

Then the good alternative using `zip` would be:

```py
def change_keys_values(d):
    a, b = zip(*d.items())
    d = dict(list(zip(b,a)))
    return d
```

Comment: He is not asking how to fix the issue, but why the error happens in one case, and not in the other.

Comment: It seems pretty random - it succeeds for 3 consecutive elements of the sample `dict`, but not for 2, or 4 - I would stick to "don't modify an iterator, while you're looping through it" line